# "Your PC ran into a problem" and it never restarts

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, windows-8, support

I had the "[Your PC ran into a problem](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/388594)" blue screen while I was using Visual Studio in Windows 8.1, and then I am never able to start Windows 8 again. Now after I set Windows as BIOS boot option 1, I can't even start GRUB anymore (before Ubuntu 14.04 was my boot option 1, Windows was option 2). Right now after I press the power button, it's just a big black screen. What should I do? I want to at least be able to start Ubuntu. Thanks.

Addition info: 
Asus Q200E, 
Intel Core i3,
[Grub's windows settings](http://tinypic.com/r/2eocrqx/8) (before I set Windows to boot option 1):

Answer (score 0):

First you need to run "scandisk /f" on the windows partition to repair any corrupt files. It has been my experience that removing the drive and placing it in another PC as a slave or external drive is the best way to accomplish this. Once scandisk has run, return the drive to its original PC and try booting (don't forget to reset any jumpers on the drive if you moved them). If it is still not booting, start an Ubuntu live DVD session and run boot-repair that should get you back booting again.